# Agile, Waterfall, Scrum... how difficult is it to transition a team into iterative development?

Tags: project-management, agile, scrum

What are the challenges of transition a team in a corporate atmosphere from a traditional non-iterative, spec list, gantt chart, phase dependent team to a more iterative approach?

Moreover, what was a successful way to gain acceptance with other groups while using a newer development strategy?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Comment: Oddly enough, this wasn't off topic 8 years ago for SO ;) but sure enough it is today!

Comment: Yeah. The fact that what's on-topic/off-topic on Stack Overflow has changed, doesn't reflect negatively on you, or this question. It's just the way the site's evolved over time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What we did:

1. Explained to management that a plan (which intends to predict the future) is simply fluff, vapor, a list of assumptions without a factual basis.
2. Planned a list of sprints.  Wrote a burndown chart.  Forgot to put in summary estimates.
3. Started executing on the list of sprints.

After the first two or three, management started to realize that the "plan" was just a burndown list, with no "dates", "risks", "assumptions" or anything like a traditional waterfall project plan.

At this point, of course, it's too late.  We've already completed one sprint and are most of the way through the second.  The horse is out of the barn.  The bell was already rung.

So management demands some stuff.

1. The total budget.  We said "Add up the sprints that are important to you.  Just draw a random line, anywhere you're happy.  That's your budget."  No one likes this, because it's too much control.  "How can you justify that?" they asked.  "Easy.  We build in priority order until you cancel the project."

   What we did have to add was a tentative duration for each sprints.  Ours are of variable size: 2 to 4 weeks.  A list of 10 sprints was about 26 weeks -- 6 months.  After that, we stopped putting down numbers.
2. The list of "assumptions".  We just refused this.  "Write your own".  They couldn't think of any on their own.  That was that.
3. The list of "risks".  Again, we asked what scared *them*.  If they were bothered by something, then perhaps they should change the priority in the burndown to address that.
4. A due date.  We turned this around and asked them to prioritize the burndown around dates and budgets and risks that were important to them.  We didn't much care what order -- it's their call as managers.

After two more sprints, they stopped making "waterfall" requests and started prioritizing and managing the burndown.

Interestingly, they never asked about scope creep.  Managers who ask "how do you control scope?" are actively rejecting incremental development.  They're trying not to get it.

When managers want to know how Agile methods "prevent" scope creep, they're (a) labeling the learning process as "creep" (which is bad) and (b) resisting the idea that learning leads to scope changes.  The only way you even have scope "creep" is when you commit to a specific scope irrespective of any learning that may happen.  Agile methods only commit to a next sprint, not a comprehensive scope.  If you don't commit to a scope, it can't creep because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thats a great point, is "how do you prevent scope creep" a synonym for "how do we resist ourselves from having to implement better design"?

Comment: +1 - I like what you're saying, my only addition is that you need to be sensitive to the culture of your organization. This approach may very well not work for you if you don't have enough folks to achieve buy-in and get that ball rolling from the top down.

Comment: We didn't get the ball rolling from the top down.  We just did it one team at a time.

Answer (score 5):

I'm in the process of trying to do this right now. We've got an on-site Customer Development department and I can tell you they are key in trying to grab buy-in for an iterative development process.

Some great answers on this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53318/effective-ways-to-introduce-agile-into-the-workplace).

If you've already got a track record of delivering projects late and over budget due to large and unmanageable chunks not getting done, that's a good start in convincing the stakeholders of your projects to get the ball of change rolling.

Process can prove itself, but only with the right parties in support of it. Your key is getting other team players to see value in what you're trying to do.

For us, it comes down to approaching things from a customers perspective. We need to constantly come back to the customer to make sure that what we're building is what they envision. We want to streamline the process to stop wasting *everyone's* time.

Now of course, different parts of Agile work for different organizations and very few companies that actually use Agile processes are doing so in a purist sense.

Through trial and error figure out what works for your business, culture and team. There is nothing that says you can't gradually adopt the overall process and cherry pick the parts that work the best for your business model.

Comment: great advice, it's hard to get customers to think that it's not just another sales tactic to sell them more hours of development.

Comment: Yeah for sure. We're lucky because we do so with an internal department who then service the customers. Really almost like a sales department would be at any other company. They want to deliver a product that meets customers expectations so they ultimately get either the sale or even better, repeat business. I try to justify an Agile approach mainly because I can help deliver functional parts of the software sooner and most of the time customers always want everything yesterday.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, transitioning the team isn't the problem.  It's transitioning management.

Comment: +1: Management just knows (without proof) that the **only** valid project plan is a waterfall plan with all tasks full defined.

Comment: Yah, and for us it's mostly about our clients. I the only thing on their mind is saving money, and knowing how much something is going to cost "out-the-door".

Answer (score 2):

You may be interest in the book [Fearless Change: Patterns for Introducing New Ideas](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201741571) by Lynn Manns and Linda Rising.  It is a compendium of experience in introducing agile methods into organizations.

Comment: +1 - Nice link. I'm all over that one. ;)

Comment: yah, this may be a new book on my bookshelf soon! nice recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

Around here it started with one team who wanted to go ahead and be more Agile using Scrum. This team was the "pilot team" and went for a few sprints (3 months). They were coached by someone from the inside who was already reading and learning about Scrum. Doing a "pilot" instead of a complete switchover helped to gain acceptance from management and refractive team members.

Having a "let's try it" attitude really help to get customers into the process also (internal customers here, but customers none the less).

And to make it stick, you have to take note of the progress made and the advantages it brings to you and your team (it can be better performance, better communication with team members/customers, better results, happier customers, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

From my (admittedly limited) experience, make sure that all your programmers are involved with the decision to switch to Agile/Scrum/whatever, and that they're all in favor of it - or at least not going to actively oppose it.  I've seen resistance from team members when Agile/Scrum was perceived to be mandated from above without their consent/input. It's hard enough to retrain managers without having to constantly convince your team as well.

Comment: This is true, rarely do mandated things inspire passion in those that it is imposed upon.